# Need help on a PHP website logic

Tags: php, pdo, logic

I am creating a contest website on my localhost using PHP. The project works as follows:

The user can log in and is directed to a page `level.php?n=getUserData()['level']` , the logic is that if the user submits the right answer the user is redirected to the next level and the level field in the database must be updated so that the user can redirected to the next level `level.php?n=2` and so on...., during login the users credentials are being stored in a session variable.(`user_id`,`level`,`email` ..etc).

My login controller:

```
include 'core/init.php';

$id = isset($_GET['n']) ? $_GET['n'] : null;
$validate = new Validator;
$template = new Template("templates/question.php");
$template->title = $validate->getQuestion($id)->body;
//$template->answer  = $validate->getQuestion($id)->answer;
$userid = getUserData()['user_id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //  echo getUserData()['level']; die();
    $data = array();
    $data['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
    $required_fields  = array("answer");
    if($validate->isRequired($required_fields))
    {
        if($validate->check_answer($_POST['answer']))
        {
            if($validate->update_level($userid)) 
            {
                redirect("level.php?n=".getUserData()['level'],"Correct Anwser","success"); 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            redirect("level.php?n=".getUserData()['level'],"Incorrect","error");
        }
    }
    else
        {
            redirect("level.php?n=".getUserData()['level'],"Empty","error");
        }

}

echo $template;

?>

`
```

My Validation class:

```
    <?php
    class Validator
    {
        private $db;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = new Database;
        }
        public function isrequired($field_array)
        {
            foreach($field_array as $field)
            {
                if(empty($_POST[''.$field.'']))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function login($username,$password)
        {
            $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
            $this->db->bind(":username",$username);
            $this->db->bind(":password",$password);
            $result = $this->db->single();
            $row = $this->db->rowCount();
            if($row>0)
            {
                $this->getData($result);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }
        }
        public function getData($row)
        {
            $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row->id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row->email;
            $_SESSION['level'] = $row->level;
        }

        public function getQuestion($id)
        {
            $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id = :id");
            $this->db->bind(":id",$id);
            $result = $this->db->single();
            return $result;
        }

        public function logout()
        {
            unset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']); 
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']); 
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            return true;
        }

        public function update_level($id)
        {
            $level = getUserData()['level']+1;
            $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET level = :level WHERE id = :id");
            $this->db->bind(":level",$level);
            $this->db->bind(":id",getUserData()['user_id']);
            $this->db->execute();
            return true;    
        }
        function check_answer($answer)
        {
            $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE correct = :answer");
            $this->db->bind(":answer",$answer);
            $row = $this->db->single();
            return $row;

        }
    }

    ?>
```

The `getUserData()` function:

```
function getUserData()
{
    $userarray = array();
    $userarray['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userarray['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $userarray['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
    $userarray['level'] = $_SESSION['level'];
    return $userarray;
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is i cant get it to redirect to the next level. For some reason, the level entry in the database is updated, but when i logout and login again i am redirected to the intended level (level2) and further.Also can u tell me if the logic i am using is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in your update portion when the user gets the answer correct. You need to update your session. I suggest you rework your script to convert the `getUserData()` into a `User` class or similar:

```
include('core/init.php');
$id     =   (isset($_GET['n']))? $_GET['n'] : null;
$validate   =   new Validator;
$template   =   new Template("templates/question.php");
# Create User class
$User       =   new User();
# Create make sure you set the files to internal array
$User->init();
# Start template
$template->title = $validate->getQuestion($id)->body;
# Fetch the id here
$userid = $User->getUserId();
# Check post
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array();
    $data['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
    $required_fields  = array("answer");
    if($validate->isRequired($required_fields)) {
        if($validate->check_answer($_POST['answer'])) {
            # Update the database
            if($validate->update_level($userid)) {
                # Increment the init() here to push the level up
                redirect("level.php?n=".$User->init(1)->getLevel(),"Correct Anwser","success"); 
            }

        }
        else {
            # Since you are not updating, don't need the init() here
            redirect("level.php?n=".$User->getLevel(),"Incorrect","error");
        }
    }
    else {
            # Since you are not updating, don't need the init() here
            redirect("level.php?n=".$User->getLevel(),"Empty","error");
    }
}

echo $template;
```

Create a user class

**User Class**

```
<?php
class User
    {
        private $userData;
        public function init($increment = 0)
            {
                # Get the current level
                $level  =   $_SESSION['level'];
                # If there is an increment
                if($increment > 0) {
                    # Increment the level
                    $level += $increment;
                    # !!!***Re-assign the session***!!!
                    $_SESSION['level']  =   $level;
                }
                # Save the internal array
                $userarray['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
                $userarray['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                $userarray['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
                # Level will be set by variable now
                $userarray['level'] = $level;
                # Save to array
                $this->userData =  (object) $userarray;
                # Return object for chaining
                return $this;
            }
        # This will call data from your internal array dynamically
        public function __call($name,$args=false)
            {
                # Strip off the "get" from the method
                $name       =   preg_replace('/^get/','',$name);
                # Split method name by upper case
                $getMethod  =   preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $name, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                # Create a variable from that split
                $getKey     =   strtolower(implode('_',$getMethod));
                # Checks if there is a key with this split name
                if(isset($this->userData->{$getKey}))
                    $getDataSet =   $this->userData->{$getKey};
                # Checks if there is a key with the raw name (no get though)
                elseif(isset($this->userData->{$name}))
                    $getDataSet =   $this->userData->{$name};
                # Returns value or bool/false
                return (isset($getDataSet))? $getDataSet : false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked, although i am having trouble understanding the __call function. and the how is it working in the level controller. init(1)..? Can u explain to me what you just did?

Comment: If it worked, please mark as such so others know it's solved. The `__call()` takes "getUserId" and removes "get" so it then is "UserId", then it takes that and turns it to "user_id", then checks if the internal `userData` as a key with that name.

Comment: By the way `__call()` is meant to create a method that the class doesn't actually have and in this case, it converts the method name. You can pretty much make `__call()` do anything.

Comment: As for the `init()` method. It's meant to just give the internal array values, so you set it at the top. Then if you want to push the level up, you add an increment value so in this case you just want to go up one level, so it increments the `level` value in both the internal array AND updates the session so it persists.

Comment: And init(1), what is that supposed to do? I mean i know its incrementing the level, but i cannot understand how and how the getLevel() function is working? Sorry for bothering you for too long.

Comment: The `init()` method in the first part gets the value from the session, then checks if there is an incremental value greater than zero. If so, it updates the `$level`, then updates the session value and also updates the internal array with that new value. The `getLevel()` method doesn't exist, so `__call()` creates that method and inside the `__call()` I convert the name of the method to the key name of the internal array. So if you add another value into the internal array like `$userarray['confused'] = true;` you can access that value using the method `->getConfused();`

Comment: I just made one change in the `init()` method =>  `$level += $increment;` This allows you to increment more than just one level (if you wanted to in the future).

Comment: I get it now!!! So i guess the __Call method is purely working regular expressions, and What exactly was wrong with my method? i mean i was also updating the session variable which was in turn updating the userArray, , I tried updating the page by using a $next variable. ($next = getUserData()['level'] +1;) ,but it wasnt working.

Comment: Basically where you went wrong is that you didn't update your $_SESSION variable to the new level. I just didn't like that you are mixing up classes and functions so I converted that function with a class that you can easily expand upon.

Comment: Your `update_level($id)` was not updating the session, just updating the database...

Comment: Thanlks I'LL keep your advice for my next project. Also how can i restrict users from accessing further levels via url?

Comment: You just check the current page and check the current level and if they don't match, redirect to the current level.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, I asked that because this method wasnt working with my previous configration and now i know why!! Thanks!

Comment: The only silly question is one that is not asked! No problem, glad to help.